# The Sum of function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have trouble with this series: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }5\,{\frac {{x}^{2\,n+3}}{4\,{n}^{2}+8\,n+3}}$
So what have I done so far is found the derivative (which is $5\,{\frac {{x}^{2\,n+2}}{2\,n+1}}$) just to get rid of $2\,n+3$ in the denominator.
I think the answer is somehow close to $\ln  \left( x+1 \right)$.
So how do I determine the sum of this series, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty} 5 \frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} $$ Taking derivaties as you suggested then gives us

$$ f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty} 5 \frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+1} =  5x\sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty}  \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} =       5x  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg( \int x^{2n} dx\bigg) =     5x \int \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ x^{2n} \bigg) dx $$

$$= 5x\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Just integrate whatever the RHS is and you're done.